# How to show only last notification received using Parse.com & Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, notifications, phonegap-plugins

How can I display only last notification?

If the device receives 5 notifications and the user does not open or delete any notification, the device shows all notifications.

I want to delete the oldest notifications and display only the last.

Using:

- Parse.com
- Phonegap 5
- https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin

Thanks!